# Is it possible to edit SSIS package from 2008 version in Data Tools 2015 and then run/deploy again package on 2008 server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have already existing system on Sql Server 2008, with SSIS. I don't have BIDS 2008 but Data Tools 2015. Is is possible to edit existing packages from 2008 in Data Tools 2015 and then run/deploy on 2008 server again? I know that I can't run newer packages on older server but what with packages created on 2008 but edited on 2015?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess this is only available from VS 2017 and later. There you can configure the compatibility level of the solution... however, haven't tried it with 2008...

Answer (score 1):

SSDT 2015 can create packages/projects for SSIS 2012, 2014 and 2016, based on your choice. You need to select target SSIS version.
Unfortunately, it cannot create packages for SSIS 2008. You need BIDS 2008 for that.
Packages for SSIS 2012 and higher cannot be run on SSIS server 2008.